# Replace generic name of s3 object put by data pipeline

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have set up a Data Pipeline to copy the contents of a DynamoDB table to s3 as well as a Python script to add CSV headers to that object - only it's currently not generic and the random object name that AWS gives the file is hard coded, meaning it'll only work once! e.g.

```
s3_client.download_file(bucket, env + '/' + timestamp + '/' + 
'85086bfb-d129-42be-8td6-3843b27718cb-004300', local_file)
```

How can we set it so that random string name is a variable that we can populate each time the script is run?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parameter to set file name in your shell command activity. Here is a sample pipeline definition that uses a parameter.

https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples/blob/master/samples/ShellCommandWithFTP/pipeline.json

See the pipelineLogUri field in the pipeline for example of how to define a parameter. See this link on how to set parameters at activation time.

https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples/tree/master/samples/ShellCommandWithFTP

Marc